# Product URL contains products ID, why?

Tags: magento-1, import, product-urls

I imported a product, its sku and url_key is "my-product". Now, when I open the product in my browser, like that:

```
www.whatever.com/my-product
```

It always redirects to

```
www.whatever.com/my-product-1234
```

where 1234 is the products id. Why is that? Where does it come from? The product looks ok in admin.

Thanks!

Comment: please change the url key of product  from admin.let me know is this effective or not? let me what is current url of product

Comment: The url key looks ok when I open the product in admin panel.

Comment: What version of Magento? Does the url change after you update and save?

Comment: are change urlkey.

Comment: Magento 1.4, no it does not change, I also refreshed the rewrites.

Comment: is this problem for all products

Comment: Yes, for all my products

Comment: There must be some extension or some configuratio  which are append product id in url

Answer (score 2):

This happens on Magento CE and on EE prior to 1.13.

The most common case I've seen is for a configurable product where its associated products all  have the same name. Naturally, you created your simples first, then the configurable.

By the time the configurable is created, its URL key is going to have the product ID appended at the end, as in your example. This has negative effects on the URL rewrites, and your URL rewrite table will grow linearly every time you reindex. It will keep growing as long as you reindex. I've seen 20 million records once for 50K products.

To prevent this problem, make sure ***all*** (simple, configurable, grouped, etc.) of your products have unique names. You will not see this problem, if they all have unique names.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, the product with such name already existed, so when you try to add new one, then will added id as prefix.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `Catalog -> URL Redirects` in admin and see if you have any redirect for `my-product`. As @MagentoSupportTeam pointed out the ID gets appended if you have two products with same URL key. Or may be you only have one proudct with that key but have permanent redirect to new key.
2. Check if you have any third party extensions doing these as @AmitBera suggested by disabling suspected extension in app/etc/modules/ and try again.
3. Is this simple/configurable product? Check if you have Visibility to `Not Visible Individually` for simple products if you are using it with configurable product having such URL keys.

Don't forget to clear cache and re-index if it still doesn't work.

Comment: your concept is clear .give you upvote